# find the finite expansion of $f$ to order $2$ in neighborhood of $0$

Tags: real-analysis

find the finite expansion of $f$ to order $2$ in the neighborhood of $0$

> $$f_(x)=\big(2e^x-\cosh(x\sqrt{2})\big)^{\left(\frac {1}{\sinh x}\right)}$$

Comment: That may possibly be the most convoluted MathJax encoding I have ever seen. `$f(x)=(2e^x-\cosh(\sqrt2x))^{1/\sinh x}$` is what you're after.

Comment: yeah thank you @Arthur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$f(x)=(2e^x-\cosh(\sqrt2x))^{1/\sinh x}=e^{2}-2e^{2}x+\frac{14}{3}e^{2}x^2+o\left(x^2\right)$$

Comment: Is the merit to be given to you or to Mathematica ? Even more important: I don't see the real benefit for the OP if there is no explanation behind...

Comment: When the OP tried somthing and explained it to us, I do the job and detail it, when he/she just asks and wants an answer, i give it with wolfram. I just had the $e^2$ the rest is wolfram ( but I know how to have it tho )

Comment: I just wanted to see if my answer was right that's why i asked